# Customize UISilder's thumb

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uislider

I have changed UISlider's thumb image.But I cant change the size of the image

```
 var image=UIImage(named: "thumb.png")                             
  slider.setThumbImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I found slider function  `slider.thumbRectForBounds` but it doesnt help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

```
func imageWith(image : UIImage, scaledToSize:CGSize ) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(scaledToSize, false, 0.0);
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledToSize.width, scaledToSize.height))
    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}


var image = UIImage(named: "thumb.png")
slider.setThumbImage(imageWith(image, scaledToSize: <YOUR_SIZE>), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: Thanks exactly what i want!